# How to see which string threw a FormatException?

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a method that parses currency strings (such as "€4.00" or "$14.50"), but sometimes there is a parsing error, and it throws a `FormatException`.

What I want to do, is to send the string that couldn't be parsed (threw the exception) to a database.

```
try
{
    string euroNumber = "€4.00";

    // Will throw a FormatException
    double parsedNumber = Double.Parse(euroNumber, NumberStyles.Currency);
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
    string stringThatThrewTheException; // should be "€4.00" in this case

    // [Omitted] Sending to server logic
}
```

Is it somehow possible? Or should I use some kind of a hack?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use tryparse instead of try/catch

Comment: Yeah, that might work, thank you!

Comment: Just to show you that there is currency format in c#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx I know this MIGHT not be the case you use it , but the more you know .. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As BugFinder said, you can use TryParse:

```
double parsedNumber;

var result = Double.TryParse(euroNumber, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out parsedNumber);
if (!result)
{
    // send error
}
```

Another alternative is to move the string outside of the scope of the try block:

```
    string euroNumber = "€4.00";
    try
    {
        // Will throw a FormatException
        double parsedNumber = Double.Parse(euroNumber, NumberStyles.Currency);
    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        // Have access to euroNumber here now
        // [Omitted] Sending to server logic
    }
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you!